# Produce output, that counts by 10, from 1000 to 0 using a while loop (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, while-loop

The title speaks for itself. I know how to create a while loop count down from 1000 to 0, that counts down by one:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  var i = 1000
  while (i > 0) {
    println(i) 
    i--
  }
}
```

BUT, I need to count down by ten: 1000, 990, 980. I'm struggling to wrap my head around it for whatever reason. Willing to lend me a hand?

(Please provide explanation. I don't just want the answer, as I want to understand! I appreciate you all!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the decreasing interval is 10, your code `i--` needs to be modified to `i -= 10`

`i--` is equivalent to `i = i -1`, subtracting 1 from the original, which does not meet your requirements.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var i = 1000
    while (i >= 0) {
        println(i)
        i -= 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop, you just have to change `i--` to `i -=10`.
But this is little more straight forward using the `for` loop.

```kotlin
for(i in 1000 downTo 0 step 10) {
    println(i)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I like the for loop waaay better as it's easier to work with. Thank you for your time!